# Is there a function in python like Path.relative_to() supporting '../' if the path is not a subpath of the other?

Tags: python, path

`Path.relative_to` is great to suppress the common prefix of two path... But if the first path is not a subdir / subfile of the second, like :

```
Path('/tmp/random/path').relative_to(Path('/tmp/random/path/etc'))
```

Then Python raises :

```
ValueError: '/tmp/random/path' is not in the subpath of '/tmp/random/path/etc' OR one path is relative and the other is absolute.
```

Is there a function that would return `Path('..')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with :

```
def relative_to(from_:Path, to:Path):
  from_ = from_.absolute()
  to = to.absolute()
  f_parts = from_.parts
  t_parts = to.parts
  common_root_len = 0
  for f, t in zip(f_parts, t_parts) :
    if f != t :
      break
    common_root_len += 1
  return Path(*(('../',) * (len(t_parts) - common_root_len)), *f_parts[common_root_len:])
```